# A more pythonic (or pandorable) way to change a list of columns to different data types

Tags: python, pandas

Often when wrangling data I have to change datatypes.

For example

```
    In [11]: import pandas as pd

    In [12]: import numpy as np

    In [13]: df =  pd.DataFrame({'col2': {0: 'apples', 1: 'oranges', 2: 'rabbit'}, 'col1': {0: 'white', 1: 'marshmallow', 2: 'bandwagon'}}
)

    In [14]: df.dtypes
    Out[14]:
    col1    object
    col2    object
    dtype: object

   In [15]: for col in cols:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
        ....:

In [16]: df.dtypes
Out[16]:
col1    category
col2    category
dtype: object
```

Is there a more pandas friendly way to do this - using for example a list comprehension? I feel that the for loop is slow...

This is a really common thing I have to do, and I'm just wondering if there's an idiom I'm not aware of.

Comment: unfortunately `df.astype('category')` doesn't work, I'm not sure there is a much better way than list comprehension or `df.apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))`, I think list comprehension is probably fastest here

Comment: How would one write a list comprehension to do this?

Comment: `pd.concat([df[col].astype('category') for col in df], axis=1)` but not sure unless you try on a large dataset if this is much faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is nice.

Another is:

```
df[['col1','col2']] = df[['col1','col2']].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))
```

**Timings**:

```
In [32]: %timeit (orig(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))
10 loops, best of 3: 41.5 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit pd.concat([df[col].astype('category') for col in df], axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop
```

Code for timings:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'col2': ['apples', 'oranges', 'rabbit'], 
                    'col1': ['white', 'marshmallow', 'bandwagon']})

df = pd.concat([df]*1000)
df = pd.concat([df]*100, axis=1)
df.columns = range(df.shape[1])

df[df.columns] = df[df.columns].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))
print (df)


df = pd.concat([df[col].astype('category') for col in df], axis=1)
print (df)


def orig(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
    return df
```

Comment: That's pretty slow too, but a decent solution.

Comment: Confirms interestingly that the concat solution is faster

Comment: Yes. I think your solution will be faster.